# MSBuild log file location

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm running msbuild in a build script and I get this error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB4166: Child node "2" exited prematurely. Shutting down. Diagnostic information may be found in files in the temporary files directory named MSBuild_*.failure.txt.
```

I cannot find the file MSBuild_*.failure.txt on my machine. Is it something that needs to be configured? If not, what would the default location for that file be?

Comment: Tried `%temp%`? that should get you to the default temporary directory...

Comment: @jessehouwing The problem is that if msbuild is running under a CI server, it prob is a diff user on the OS than your interactive user, so the msbuild output needs to specify the dir....

Answer (score 2):

You can run

`msbuild /v:diag > c:\log.txt`

to force your log file to go to `c:\log.txt`.

Alternative, you may use `/flp:filename=c:\log.txt`, more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx).