# Where does msbuild put its failure log files?

Tags: .net, msbuild

We are chasing an issue never seen before in many years of .net development:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB4166: Child node "5" exited prematurely. Shutting down. 
Diagnostic information may be found in files in the temporary files 
directory named MSBuild_*.failure.txt.
```

We have no idea what is going on. This build machine has been in service for months, and runs builds under a CI system.

The question is: What dir do I look in for the diag files?  I searched the whole system for msbuild*.txt , and find nothing.

The bigger question is... why can't msbuild.exe be more specific in its output RE exactly where the diag file is. msbuild.exe runs as a different user under CI, and it should be explicit where it is putting things.

Comment: According to https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/cb8c727a898e4439a3cd18f329504e436b0b7c00/src/Shared/ExceptionHandling.cs#L294 the file should be in one of these directories: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365307/what-determines-the-return-value-of-path-gettemppath#2365338

Comment: exact duplicate (unanswered though) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515424/where-does-msbuild-put-its-failure-log-files

Comment: @stijn - Your link points to this same question.

Comment: I think you may have meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458184/msbuild-log-file-location

Comment: ^ yeah sorry that's the one indeed.